# Get week days and specific time of day

Tags: javascript

I'm using javaScript to display an element on week days and in busines hours (Monday to Friday between 08:00 and 16:50).

I'm using this code:

```
var date = new Date();
var thisMin = date.getMinutes();
var thisHour = date.getHours();
var thisWeekday = date.getDay();
// True if Mon - Fri between 08:00 - 16:50
if (thisWeekday > 0 && thisWeekday < 6 && thisHour > 7 && (thisHour < 17 && thisMin <= 50)) {
    alert("True");
} else {
    alert("False");
}
```

- but is this the best way to code it? It seems like a lot of conditions and it's working all the time... Can it be done in a better way with javaScript?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7LYZ/).

Thanks.

Comment: Your condition fails, for example 13:53 is a valid time but false is alerted, you would have to check `thisMinutes <= 50` only if `thisHour === 16`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what should my code look like then?

Comment: `thisWeekday > 0 && thisWeekday < 6 && thisHour > 7 && (thisHour < 16 || (thisHour === 16 && thisMin <= 50))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have a condition with two distinct parts "must be within week interval" and "must be within time interval".  The code can reflect this more clearly by being explicit.

For the time comparison I would reshape the current time so that you can use `Date`'s `<=` and `>=` operators instead of reimplementing time comparisons yourself:

```
var startTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 8, 0);
var endTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 50);
var startWeekday = 1;
var endWeekday = 5;

function shouldDisplay() {
    var d = new Date();

    function withinWeekInterval() {
        return (d.getDay() >= startWeekday &&
                d.getDay() <= endWeekday);
    }

    function withinTimeInterval() {
        var now = new Date(0, 0, 0, d.getHours(), d.getMinutes());
        return (now >= startTime &&
                now <= endTime);
    }

    return (withinWeekInterval() && withinTimeInterval());
}
```

Manual test:

```
alert(shouldDisplay());
```

Comment: This looks promising. How do I use this function in an if / else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code :

```
var date = new Date();
var thisMin = date.getMinutes();
var thisHour = date.getHours();
var thisWeekday = date.getDay();
var isSuccess = false;
// True if Mon - Fri between 08:00 - 16:50
if (thisWeekday > 0 && thisWeekday < 6 && thisHour > 7 && (thisHour < 17)) {
    if (thisHour == 16 && thisMin > 50) {
        isSuccess = false;
    } else {
        isSuccess = true;
    }
} else {
    isSuccess = false;
}

alert(isSuccess);
```